# Syntax of Javascript TAPE unit test

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing

I'm new to unit testing for javascript and node-js.  I'm trying to figure out the syntax of the following TAPE unit test:

```
test('player has computed fields', (assert) => {
    const playerData = {
        firstName: 'Test',
        lastName: 'Testerton'
    };

  var player = new Player(playerData);

  assert.equal(`${player.fullName}`,
                `${playerData.firstName} ${playerData.lastName}`,
                'has full name');
  assert.end();
});
```

I understand basically what's going on, but the syntax is hard to reference anywhere.  For example is the '=>' a conditional or fancy arrow syntax format?

This would read to me as make sure it's not empty if this was a conditional.

Comment: Greater or equal is `>=`. `=>` is always an arrow function syntax.

Comment: @zerkms thank you, that makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@zerkms put me on the right track.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/06/es6-in-depth-arrow-functions/